# How to give root permission for app even after unrooted?

Tags: root-access

I'm using 4.4.2 so ES explorer can't write to SD card. I intend to give the app root permission permernently (like system apps) and then unroot the device. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Well,I think the answer is no. If you got your device rooted then is rooted for all apps. Well, virtually all apps. Superuser is the app that avoids that any app use superuser permissions. If you unroot then nobody can access root